# "Template is missing" error. Missing Template Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, view

I try to displaying Validation Errors in the View for create new article page. I have validation in article model for check body and title presence ( validates :title, :body, :presence => true). It did not allow to  create new article when I keep article and title text box but showing "Template is missing" error with below info.

```
Missing template articles/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "F:/kuta/billi/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.6/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views"
```

I have put <%= f.error_messages %> in partial for new page of article and put gem 'dynamic_form' in gemfile.

_form.html.erb for article/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @article, :html => { :class => '' } do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :title, :style => "margin-top:10px;" %>
    <div>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :style => "width:730px; height:30px; border: 1px solid #66c9ee;margin-top:10px; background-color:#FFFFFF;" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
   <%= f.text_area :body, :style => "width:730px; height:250px; border: 1px solid #66c9ee;margin-top:10px; background-color:#FFFFFF;" %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, :style => "margin-top:10px" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :style => "width:730px; height:30px; border: 1px solid #66c9ee;margin-top:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF;" %>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                articles_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

article.rb model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body
   attr_accessible :tag_list
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, through: :taggings
   validates :title, :body, :presence => true


   def tag_list
    self.tags.collect do |tag|
     tag.name
    end.join(", ")
   end

   def tag_list=(tags_string)
    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name) }
    self.tags = new_or_found_tags
   end
end
```

Could you please help me , where I am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When validations fail, in your controller action you should render the new template again with `render 'new'` instead of `render 'create'`

Comment: hi zippie, your suggestion worked for me. Thanks. but validation errors appears without any color (basically it should be in red). any idea how to get color on them. thanks.

Comment: when they are shown, make a right-click -> inspect element and see what class or id the div that's wrapped around them has. once you find out make them red with css